# Zend Project not working in a real server after upload

Tags: zend-framework

I just completed the job site using zend framework. This is my first project using Zend framework. The site is almost finished in localhost and i tried to upload it in real server for testing. I put my files under public_html folder of real server. I noticed there is no any file "index.php" inside root folder of project(ie public_html). It actually lies inside public folder inside public_html. I am bewildered. I tried to make index.php inside root folder and put "require_once('public/index.php'), but didn't work. What should i do now?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a [typical project directory structure](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/project-structure.project.html), your `public` folder should go inside your server's `public_html` folder, and all other Zend project folders should go one level up, like this:

```
/application
    // application files
/library
    // library and vendor files
/public (aka public_html, htdocs etc)
    index.php
    .htaccess
    /css
    /images
    /js
```

Comment: i prefer to keep nonpublic stuff in /basedir so application directories(like app, library, data, tests etc) are not mixed with other stuff

Comment: I'd do that for shared/reduced control environments, but assuming he uses the conventional ZF directory structure and can upload like for like structures, this is how you'd do it.

Comment: My structure was as you said, coz i started the project installing sample project. Actually the PDO extension was disabled in server, and it works now after enabling it...
Thanks a lot adlawson ))

Answer (score 1):

If you can, configure a vhost on your server, and make it point to the "public" folder of your application.

You should also enable the rewrite module of apache and ensure that your vhost accepts .htaccess files (directive AllowOverride All in your vhost).

Comment: Benjamin i moved the .htaccess outside public and after enabling PDO extension is server, the project works now.....thanks a lot ))

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it, is to have the `index.php` and `.htacess` 1 level up from the public directory and alter the paths defined in index.php accordingly.

e.g

`set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));`

Comment: i put .htaccess file one level up and changed configuration there.
Thanks a lot shane....the code works after i enable PDO extension from server ))

Comment: You're welcome. If you 'accept' the answer, then click the green arrow. The more you accept answers, the more help you are likely to get.